# Unable to launch Firefox debugger from VSCode "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded"

Tags: firefox, 22.04, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Firefox 100.0.1 without problems on Ubuntu 22 however when I try to launch a debugger from VSCode I get the following errors:

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.

connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6000
```

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Multiple restarts
2. Re-install Firefox from Ubuntu Software
3. `sudo apt purge firefox`
4. Removed `.mozilla` and `.cache/mozilla` folders
5. `firefox -p` and removing all profiles

Answer (score 9):

The firefox snap does not have access to /tmp, so you have to provide another folder in the tmpDir property in the launch.json configuration, like this:

```
    {
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch My Firefox",
        "url": "https://myurl",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "timeout": 90000,
        "tmpDir": "/some/folder/of/yours/with/write/perms"
    },
```

This is from a [fix](https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug/issues/200) by the author of the vscode Firefox Debug plugin.

Comment: Thx! NB : the tmpDir needs to be adapted to your own home directory ("/home/.../backup")

Comment: I'll edit answer, ty.

Comment: a life saver, thank you.

Comment: Doesn't fix and gives a warning saying "Property tempDir is not allowed."

Comment: Yeah the Debugger for Firefox vscode plugin stopped working well for me too.  Honestly I really really want to use FF for my dev but I switched to Chrome bc vscode support for FF is so dicey.  I can't get it to work properly at all with profiles.